# Opening IE in HTA VBScript - doesn't support "navigate"

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, hta

For specific reasons, I'm trying to open an Internet Explorer window from within an HTA and navigate to a specific URL.

After some searching, I came across the solution below. I successfully opens an Internet Explorer, but I get told that the IE object doesn't support Navigate?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <hta:application
        id="oHTA"
        applicationname="Test"
        application="yes"
        icon=""
    >
    </hta:application>

    <script language="VBScript">
        Sub Sleep(seconds)
            CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "%COMSPEC% /c ping 127.0.0.1 -n " & seconds+1, 0, True
        End Sub

        Function openGoogle()

            Set webBrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
            webBrowser.Visible = True
            webBrowser.Navigate = "https://google.co.uk/"

            Do While webBrowser.ReadyState <> 4 Or webBrowser.Busy
                Sleep 5
            Loop

        End Function

        openGoogle()

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this : [HTA opens internet explorer on enterbutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22416941/hta-opens-internet-explorer-on-enterbutton)

And also, you can get inspired from this old HTA (French Version) that let you launch some commands from the  command line and, therefore, you can open any link with any browsers installed on your system !

Just give a try for this code :

```
<html>
<head>
<HTA:APPLICATION
APPLICATIONNAME="Ouvrir des liens avec les navigateurs IE,Chrome et Firefox"
BORDER="THIN"
BORDERSTYLE="NORMAL"
ICON="Explorer.exe"
INNERBORDER="NO"
MAXIMIZEBUTTON="NO"
MINIMIZEBUTTON="NO"
SCROLL="NO"
SELECTION="NO"
SINGLEINSTANCE="YES"/>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="MSThemeCompatible" CONTENT="YES">
<title>Ouvrir des liens avec les navigateurs IE,Chrome et Firefox</title>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
'******
Option Explicit
 Function Executer(StrCmd,Console)
 Dim ws,MyCmd,Resultat
 Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
'La valeur 0 pour cacher la console MS-DOS
 If Console = 0 Then
 MyCmd = "CMD /C " & StrCmd & " "
 Resultat = ws.run(MyCmd,Console,True)
 If Resultat = 0 Then
 'MsgBox "Success"
 Else
 MsgBox "Une erreur inconnue est survenue !",16,"Une erreur inconnue est survenue !"
 End If
 End If
'La valeur 1 pour montrer la console MS-DOS
 If Console = 1 Then
 MyCmd = "CMD /K " & StrCmd & " "
 Resultat = ws.run(MyCmd,Console,False)
 If Resultat = 0 Then
 'MsgBox "Success"
 Else
 MsgBox "Une erreur inconnue est survenue !",16,"Une erreur inconnue est survenue !"
 End If
 End If
 Executer = Resultat
End Function
'******
Sub window_onload()
 CenterWindow 400,320
End Sub
'******
Sub CenterWindow(x,y)
 Dim iLeft,itop
 window.resizeTo x,y
 iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2
 itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2
 window.moveTo ileft,itop
End Sub
'******
Sub Ip_Publique()
 Dim Titre,URL,ie,objFSO,Data,OutPut,objRegex,Match,Matches,ip_public
 Titre = "Adresse Ip Publique !"
 URL = "http://monip.org"
 If OnLine("smtp.gmail.com") = True Then
 Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 ie.Navigate (URL)
 ie.Visible=False
 DO WHILE ie.busy
 Sleep 100
 Loop
 Data = ie.document.documentElement.innertext
 Set objRegex = new RegExp
 objRegex.Pattern = "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b"
 objRegex.Global = False
 objRegex.IgnoreCase = True
 Set Matches = objRegex.Execute(Data)
 For Each Match in Matches
 MsgBox "Votre IP Publique est : "& Match.Value,64,Titre
 Next
 ie.Quit
 Set ie = Nothing
 Else
 MsgBox "Vérifier votre connexion internet puis re-executer ce script",48,Titre
 Exit Sub
 End If
End Sub

'******
Sub Sleep(MSecs)'Fonction pour faire une pause car wscript.sleep ne marche pas dans un HTA
 Dim fso,objOutputFile
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim tempFolder : Set tempFolder = fso.GetSpecialFolder(2)
    Dim tempName : tempName = "Sleeper.vbs"
    If Fso.FileExists(tempFolder&"\"&tempName)=False Then
      Set objOutputFile = fso.CreateTextFile(tempFolder&"\"&tempName, True)
      objOutputFile.Write "wscript.sleep WScript.Arguments(0)"
      objOutputFile.Close
    End If
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run tempFolder&"\"&tempName &" "& MSecs,1,True
End Sub
'******
Sub SSID_names()
Dim objShell,fso,File,strContents,objRegEx,objMatch,colMatches
 set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 If Executer("netsh wlan show all > Wlan.txt",0) = 0 Then
 Set File = fso.OpenTextFile("Wlan.txt",1)
 strContents = File.ReadAll
 Set objRegEx = New RegExp
 objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
 objRegEx.Global = True
 objRegEx.Multiline = True
 objRegEx.Pattern = """([^""]+)"""
 set colMatches = objRegEx.Execute(strContents)
 For each objMatch in colMatches
 MsgBox "SSID name: " & objMatch.Value,64,"SSID name"
 Next
 End If
End sub
'******
Function OnLine(strHost)
Dim objPing,z,objRetStatus,PingStatus
    Set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}").ExecQuery("select * from Win32_PingStatus where address = '" & strHost & "'")
    z = 0
    Do   
      z = z + 1
      For Each objRetStatus In objPing
      If IsNull(objRetStatus.StatusCode) Or objRetStatus.StatusCode <> 0 Then
            PingStatus = False
      Else
            PingStatus = True
      End If     
    Next   
      sleep 200
      If z = 4 Then Exit Do
    Loop until PingStatus = True
    If PingStatus = True Then
      OnLine = True
    Else
      OnLine = False
    End If
End Function
'******
Sub WLAN_Networks()
 If Executer("netsh wlan show profiles > Wlan_tmp.txt & netsh wlan show networks >> Wlan_tmp.txt & netsh wlan show interfaces >> Wlan_tmp.txt & cmd /U /C Type Wlan_tmp.txt > Wlan_Networks.txt",0) = 0 Then
 Call Executer("Start Wlan_Networks.txt & Del Wlan_tmp.txt",0)
 End If
End Sub
</script>
</head>
<p>Une liste de liens :</p>
<ol>
<li><a href="#" onClick="Call Executer('Start iexplore.exe www.google.com',0)">Lien Google avec iexplore.exe</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick="Call Executer('Start chrome.exe http://bbat.forumeiro.com/',0)">Lien BBAT avec Chrome.exe</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick="Call Executer('Start Firefox.exe www.developpez.net',0)">Lien developpez.net avec Firefox.exe</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick="Call Executer('Start chrome.exe www.yahoo.fr',0)">Lien Yahoo avec Chrome.exe</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick="Call Executer('Start chrome.exe www.autoitscript.fr',0)">Lien Autoitscript.fr (Français) avec Chrome.exe</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick="Call Executer('Start chrome.exe www.autoitscript.com',0)">Lien autoitscript.com (Anglais) avec Chrome.exe</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick="Call Executer('Start www.sfr.fr',0)">Lien SFR avec votre navigateur par défaut</a></li>
</ol>
<BODY text=white bgcolor="DarkOrange" TOPMARGIN="1" LEFTMARGIN="1">
 <center><button onclick="Call Executer('mode con cols=90 lines=15 & Color 0A & Title Ping sur www.developpez.net by Hackoo & Ping www.developpez.net',1)">Ping sur developpez.net</button>
 <center><button onclick="Call Executer('FindStr /? > HelpFindStrTmp.txt & cmd /U /C Type HelpFindStrTmp.txt > HelpFindStr.txt & start HelpFindStr.txt',0)">Help sur FindStr</button>
 <button onclick="Call Executer('ipconfig /all > configTmp.txt & cmd /U /C Type configTmp.txt > MyIPconfig.txt & start MyIPconfig.txt',0)">IpConfig</button>
 <button onclick="Call Executer('mode con cols=80 lines=50 & Color 9B & Title Hackoo & netstat -a',1)">Netstat</button>
 <button onclick="Call Executer('mode con cols=60 lines=10 & Color 0A & Title Hackoo & arp -a',1)">Arp</button>
 <button onclick="Call Executer('mode con cols=80 lines=30 & Color 9B & Title Tracert vers www.developpez.com by Hackoo & Tracert www.developpez.com',1)">Tracert</button><br>
 <center><button onclick="Call Ip_Publique">IP Publique</button>
 <button onclick="Call SSID_names()">SSID WLAN</button>
  <button onclick="Call WLAN_Networks()">WLAN Network</button>
 </center>
 </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Navigate` is a subroutine and not a property. Change

```
webBrowser.Navigate = "https://google.co.uk/"
```

to

```
webBrowser.Navigate "https://google.co.uk/"
```